# Probability and coin tosses

Tags: probability

Taking a Probability & Statistics class this term and trying to get my head wrapped around how I calculate coin tosses with specific out comes in mind. We're using the nCr and nPr functions on our calculators to speed the calculations along. $^nP_r = n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-(r+1)$  and $^nC_r=\large \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} $

If I toss a coin 8 times and want to know the odds of heads coming up 3 times then I use $^8C_3$ for my total # of possible valid results over $2^8$.  I use $^nC_r$ because its unordered.

However, if I do care that heads comes up 3 times at **specific positions** within the sequence or **tails appears on the last toss**, would I use $\large \frac{^8P_3 + ^8P_1}{2^8}$  or just $\large \frac{^8P_4}{2^8}$?

[Edit]

It appears that I misunderstood the method in general.  The events were not exclusive of each other.  The odds of heads coming up in the first three places OR tails coming up as the last is what was a win situation.  That should give me $\large \frac{(2^5 + 2^1 - 2^3)}{2^8}$

I hope I got that correct.  Anyone care to confirm for me?

Comment: I don't know what a "win" is for your second question. I cannot think of any reasonable question about coin tossing in which we end up using the "permutation symbol".

Comment: You ask: "If I do care that X or Y, ..." What do you want, X or Y or both?

Comment: I think that total possibility will be 16 and not $2^8$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well then you are dealing with two events. The
first is that head turns up at $3$ specific positions. In your question
it is unclear whether head is allowed to turn up at other positions
or not. Let's say it is (if not then have a look at the answer of Eupraxis1981) and denote the event by $A$. The second
is that tail appears on the last toss. Let's denote it by $B$. You
are asking for $P\left(A\text{ or }B\right)$. Then formula: $$P\left(A\text{ or }B\right)=P\left(A\right)+P\left(B\right)-P\left(A\text{ and }B\right)$$
can be practicized. This - if the coin is a fair one - with $P\left(A\right)=2^{-3}$
and $P\left(B\right)=2^{-1}$.

Note that it matters what the specific
positions are. If the last toss is one of them then $P\left(A\text{ and }B\right)=0$
but in other cases $P\left(A\text{ and }B\right)=P\left(A\right)\times P\left(B\right)=2^{-4}$.

Answer (score 0):

> If I toss a coin 8 times and want to know the odds of heads coming up 3 times then I use $^8C_3$ for my total # of possible valid results over $2^8$.  I use $^nC_r$ because its unordered.

More specifically: $^nC_r$ counts the distinct ways to select $r$ items from a set of $n$ ... such as a set of tosses.   By the Binomial Expansion Theorem: $(1+1)^8=\sum_{r=0}^8{^8C_r}$.   So ${^8C_3}/2^8$ is the probability for obtaining exactly 3 heads among the 8 tosses, when we may obtain any number of heads among them (and the coins are unbiased).

---

> However, if I do care that heads comes up 3 times at **specific positions** within the sequence or **tails appears on the last toss**, would I use $\large \frac{^8P_3 + ^8P_1}{2^8}$  or just $\large \frac{^8P_4}{2^8}$?

${^nP_r} = {^nC_r}\, r!$ and counts the ways to select *and arrange* $r$ items from a set of $n$.  This is *not appropriate* for this situation; where the 'items' being selected *are* the positions (of heads among the tosses).

**Don't simply think of $\boldsymbol{^nC_r}$ as "counting unordered", and $\boldsymbol{^nP_r}$ as "counting ordered".  Also consider *what* is being counted.**

---

> It appears that I misunderstood the method in general.  The events were not exclusive of each other.  The odds of heads coming up in the first three places OR tails coming up as the last is what was a win situation.  That should give me $\large \frac{(2^5 + 2^1 - 2^3)}{2^8}$

No, it is : $\dfrac{1^3\,2^5+2^7\,1^1-1^3\,2^4\,1^1}{2^8}$ , the probability for $3$ consecutive heads then five whatever, or seven consecutive whatever then a tail, discounting the common outcomes (as per then Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion), among eight unbiased-coin tosses.

$$\dfrac{2^5+2^7-2^4}{2^8} =  2^{-3}+2^{-1}-2^{-4}$$

---